# how to read email signature from current email in outlook add-in form region?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook-addin

I am developing one form region in my outlook 2010 add-in with c#.net in visual studio 2010.

I want to read signature of current-opened email.

How can i read signature from email ?

I tried to google but i couldn't find anything. Most of the solutions shows about how to set the signature or access signature from default templates.

but i want to read it from an email.

can anyone help me ?

-
Thanks in advance.

Mausami

Answer (score 0):

The signature is just part of the email body and not stored separately. All outlook does is append the signature HTML onto the bottom of the email, so you would have to try to  differentiate the signature from the content of the email somehow. I imagine this would be very difficult, there is no way that you can just call a function and retrieve the sig.

Comment: Thanks a lot LachlanB for quick response. Is there any way to differentiate the email text and the signature from email body ?

Comment: Unless all the signature's conform to a standard, which they don't because people can enter whatever they want, no I don't think there is a way.